# How do I get a unique number in array

Tags: java

```
number = {5,3,5,5,5,6,6,9,3,3};
```

How do I get a unique number which is not duplicated in array?

What I want to get

```
9
```

My code is below

```
int[] list = {5,3,5,5,5,6,6,9,3,3};
Arrays.sort(list);
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
                if(list[i] == list[j]){
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: what exactly have you tried to filter out the unique value(s)?

Comment: In your code you have sorted the array so you can define a value as unique if it is not equal to both its predecessor or successor within that sorted array.  What if your array contains multiple unique numbers? e.g. [2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6]

Comment: Using HashSet class as intermediate temporary and result set's @coala:
  `int[] list = {5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 5};`

      `Set<Integer> temp   = new HashSet<>();`
      `Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();`

      `for (Integer val : list) {`
      `if (temp.contains(val)) result.remove(val);`
      `else {`
       `temp.add(val);`
      `result.add(val);`
     `}`
     `}`
     `System.out.println(result);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute force approach but can solve you problem.

```
public static int GetUnique(int val){
    int count = 0;
    int[] list = {5,3,5,5,5,6,6,9,3,3};
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
            if(list[i] == list[j]){
                count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == 1)
        return list[i];
    count = 0;
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.  `i` is out of scope when you reference it outside the loop and you are setting `count` to 0 after the `return` in the if-block. Why are you passing in `val` as an argument?

Comment: i is inside the scope might be there needs extra prantheses and I am retuning because it a return type function if there no value same return 0 our you can also return -1.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way of finding non repeating elements from given array would be by using [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table):

Construct a hash table consisting of element and it's occurrence count by traversing the given array

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hashTable = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(hashTable.containsKey(list[i])) {
            hashTable.put(list[i], hashTable.get(list[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            hashTable.put(list[i], 1);
        }
    }
```

Once the hash table is ready, then any desired operations on it can be performed. For example: If first non repeating number is to be found, then a simple iteration on the given list would suffice:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if(hashTable.get(list[i]) == 1) {
                System.out.println(list[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Time complexity of this approach is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Java Stream API:

```java
Integer[] list = {5,3,5,5,5,6,6,9,3,3,13};
Map<Integer, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(list)
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
int[] uniqueValues = counts.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(1L)).mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey).toArray();
```

Output:

```
[9, 13]
```

This is what happened:

1. First, numbers have been grouped by occurrences in format: `number: occurrences of number`:

```
3:  3 occurrences
5:  4 occurrences
6:  2 occurrences
9:  1 occurrence
13: 1 occurrence
```

2. In next step we filter above groups by leaving **only** numbers with 1 occurrence and mapping result into final array

Answer (score 0):

`If list[i-1] != list[i] and list[i]!=list[i+1]` Then, it's necessary to manage start and end of the array, otherwise arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException raise.

```
    int[] list = {3,3,5,6,6,9,9,15};
Arrays.sort(list);

for(int i = 0; i <list.length; i++){


    
        if( (i==0 && (list[i]!=list[i+1])) || ((i>0) && (list[i]!=list[i-1]) && (( i==list.length-1) || (list[i+1]!=list[i]))) ){
            System.out.println(list[i]);
            break;
        }
}
```